# Amazon Cloudformation issue with creating instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use cloud formation to build a stack, but It's returning a error I can't seem to solve.

Also I'm not entirely sure I'm doing the IAM Role correctly for S3.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
14:06:25 UTC-0700   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  anothertest The following resource(s) failed to create: [ElasticSearchNodeDev1, ElasticSearchMasterDev1]. . Rollback requested by user.
14:06:23 UTC-0700   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Instance  ElasticSearchMasterDev1 Value of property IamInstanceProfile must be of type String
14:06:23 UTC-0700   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Instance  ElasticSearchNodeDev1   Value of property IamInstanceProfile must be of type String
```

The code

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Parameters" : {
    "KeyName": {
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    },

    "InstanceType" : {
      "Description" : "WebServer EC2 instance type",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "m1.small",
      "AllowedValues" : [ "t1.micro", "t2.micro", "t2.small", "t2.medium", "m1.small", "m1.medium", "m1.large", "m1.xlarge", "m2.xlarge", "m2.2xlarge", "m2.4xlarge", "m3.medium", "m3.large", "m3.xlarge", "m3.2xlarge", "c1.medium", "c1.xlarge", "c3.large", "c3.xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c3.4xlarge", "c3.8xlarge", "c4.large", "c4.xlarge", "c4.2xlarge", "c4.4xlarge", "c4.8xlarge", "g2.2xlarge", "r3.large", "r3.xlarge", "r3.2xlarge", "r3.4xlarge", "r3.8xlarge", "i2.xlarge", "i2.2xlarge", "i2.4xlarge", "i2.8xlarge", "hi1.4xlarge", "hs1.8xlarge", "cr1.8xlarge", "cc2.8xlarge", "cg1.4xlarge"]
,
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },

    "SSHLocation" : {
      "Description" : "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
   }
  },

  "Mappings" : {
    "AWSInstanceType2Arch" : {
      "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "t2.micro"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.small"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m1.small"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m1.large"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m3.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "c1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "c3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "g2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVMG2"  },
      "r3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "hi1.4xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "hs1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "cr1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "cc2.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  }
    }
,
    "AWSRegionArch2AMI" : {
      "us-east-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-8e682ce6", "HVM64" : "ami-146e2a7c", "HVMG2" : "ami-7200461a"},
      "us-west-2"        : {"PV64" : "ami-9fc29baf", "HVM64" : "ami-dfc39aef", "HVMG2" : "ami-0b78203b"},
      "us-west-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-f49089b1", "HVM64" : "ami-42908907", "HVMG2" : "ami-244b5361"},
      "eu-west-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-7b3db00c", "HVM64" : "ami-9d23aeea", "HVMG2" : "ami-4d7cf03a"},
      "eu-central-1"     : {"PV64" : "ami-0600331b", "HVM64" : "ami-04003319", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "ap-northeast-1"   : {"PV64" : "ami-3c87993d", "HVM64" : "ami-18869819", "HVMG2" : "ami-2e90892f"},
      "ap-southeast-1"   : {"PV64" : "ami-58ba910a", "HVM64" : "ami-96bb90c4", "HVMG2" : "ami-3e78526c"},
      "ap-southeast-2"   : {"PV64" : "ami-1500742f", "HVM64" : "ami-d50773ef", "HVMG2" : "ami-315e2a0b"},
      "sa-east-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-fd9925e0", "HVM64" : "ami-af9925b2", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "cn-north-1"       : {"PV64" : "ami-8a1d8fb3", "HVM64" : "ami-981d8fa1", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"}
    }

  },

  "Resources" : {
    "ElasticSearchBackups" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "Properties":{
        "AccessControl":"PublicRead"
        }
    },

    "ElasticSearchELB" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
        "Properties" :{
        "AvailabilityZones" : ["us-east-1c"],
        "Instances" : [ { "Ref" : "ElasticSearchMasterDev1" },{ "Ref" : "ElasticSearchNodeDev1" }],
        "Listeners" : [ {
        "LoadBalancerPort" : "443",
        "InstancePort" : "80",
        "Protocol" : "HTTP"
        }],
        "HealthCheck" : {
          "Target" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", ["HTTP:80/", "443", "/"]]},
          "HealthyThreshold" : "3",
          "UnhealthyThreshold" : "5",
          "Interval" : "30",
          "Timeout" : "5"
        }
      }
     },

    "ElasticSearchMasterDev1" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1c",
        "InstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
        "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
        "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "ImageId" : "ami-4e3a6226",
        "Monitoring": "true",
        "DisableApiTermination": "false",
        "IamInstanceProfile": [{"Ref": "RootInstanceProfile"}],
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [{
            "DeviceName" : "/dev/sdf",
            "Ebs" : {
              "DeleteOnTermination" : "true",
              "VolumeSize" : "80"
            }
        }],
        "UserData": { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["",
        [
          "---\n",
          "hostname: esm1-dev.n.chronotrack.com\n",
          "run_list:recipe[ct-server-base::default]\n"
        ]]}},
        "Tags": [{"Key": "Name", "Value": "esm1-dev"}]
      }
    },


    "ElasticSearchNodeDev1" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1c",
        "InstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
        "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
        "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "ImageId" : "ami-4e3a6226",
        "Monitoring": "true",
        "DisableApiTermination": "false",
        "IamInstanceProfile": [{"Ref": "RootInstanceProfile"}],
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [{
            "DeviceName" : "/dev/sdf",
            "Ebs" : {
              "DeleteOnTermination" : "true",
              "VolumeSize" : "80"
            }
        }],
        "UserData": { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["",
        [
          "---\n",
          "hostname: esn1-dev.n.chronotrack.com\n",
          "run_list:recipe[ct-server-base::default]\n"
        ]]}},
        "Tags": [{"Key": "Name", "Value": "esn1-dev"}]
      }
    },

    "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH access via port 22",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "22",
          "ToPort" : "22",
          "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}
        },
        {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "9300",
          "ToPort" : "9300",
          "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}
        } ,
        {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "80",
          "ToPort" : "80",
          "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}
        },
        {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "8080",
          "ToPort" : "8080",
          "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}
        },
        {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "443",
          "ToPort" : "443",
          "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}
        }]
      }
    },

      "ElasticSearchRole":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Properties":{
            "Path":"/",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
               "Version":"2012-10-17",
               "Statement":[{
               "Effect":"Allow",
               "Principal":{"Service":["ec2.amazonaws.com"]},
               "Action":["sts:AssumeRole"]
               }]
            }
         }
      },
      "RolePolicies":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Policy",
         "Properties":{
            "Roles":[{"Ref": "ElasticSearchRole"}],
            "PolicyName":"root",
            "PolicyDocument":{
               "Version":"2012-10-17",
               "Statement":[{
                   "Action"   : "s3:*",
                   "Effect"   : "Allow",
                   "Resource" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:s3:::", { "Ref" : "ElasticSearchBackups" } , "-userdata/*" ] ] }
                  }]
            }
         }
      },

    "RootInstanceProfile":{
        "Type":"AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
        "Properties":{
            "Path":"/",
            "Roles":[{"Ref":"ElasticSearchRole"}]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please [simplify the code to give a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 4):

It was

```
"IamInstanceProfile": [{"Ref": "RootInstanceProfile"}],
```

needs to be

```
"IamInstanceProfile": {"Ref": "RootInstanceProfile"},
```